# Finding unique elements in an string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

C bothers me with its handling of strings. I have a pseudocode like this in my mind:

```
char *data[20]; 

char *tmp; int i,j;

for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
  tmp = data[i]; 
  for(j=1;j<20;j++) 
  {
    if(strcmp(tmp,data[j]))
      //then except the uniqueness, store them in elsewhere
  }
}
```

But when i coded this the results were bad.(I handled all the memory stuff,little things etc.) The problem is in the second loop obviously :D. But i cannot think any solution. How do i find unique strings in an array.

Example input : abc def abe abc def deg entered
unique ones : abc def abe deg should be found.

Comment: Sorting the array first will get you a long ways.  Then just iterate over the strings, and if the current string differs from the previous string, it is unique and you can store it elsewhere.

Comment: the problem is i need the exact locations. You know like in this :
input : abc def abe abc def deg entered 
unique ones : abc def abe deg
if i sorted the array i will get unique ones like that : abc abe def deg

This isn't what i want i need the locations aswell.

Comment: Then create an array of pointers or an array of array indices into the initial array that you sort, instead of sorting the initial array.

Comment: He could also try building a hash table, although for only 20 items or so that would definitely be overkill.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to force the duplicates next to each other.  Once sorted, you only need to compare adjacent entries to find duplicates.  The result is O(N log N) rather than (I think) O(N^2).

Here is the 15 minute lunchtime version with no error checking:

```
  typedef struct {
     int origpos;
     char *value;
  } SORT;

  int qcmp(const void *x, const void *y) {
     int res = strcmp( ((SORT*)x)->value, ((SORT*)y)->value );
     if ( res != 0 )
        return res;
     else
        // they are equal - use original position as tie breaker
        return ( ((SORT*)x)->origpos - ((SORT*)y)->origpos );
  }

  int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
  {
     SORT *sorted;
     char **orig;
     int i;
     int num = argc - 1;

     orig = malloc( sizeof( char* ) * ( num ));
     sorted = malloc( sizeof( SORT ) * ( num ));

     for ( i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        orig[i] = argv[i + 1];
        sorted[i].value = argv[i + 1];
        sorted[i].origpos = i;
        }

     qsort( sorted, num, sizeof( SORT ), qcmp );

     // remove the dups (sorting left relative position same for dups)
     for ( i = 0; i < num - 1; i++ ) {
        if ( !strcmp( sorted[i].value, sorted[i+1].value ))
           // clear the duplicate entry however you see fit
           orig[sorted[i+1].origpos] = NULL;  // or free it if dynamic mem
        }

     // print them without dups in original order
     for ( i = 0; i < num; i++ )
        if ( orig[i] )
           printf( "%s ", orig[i] );

     free( orig );
     free( sorted );
  }
```

Comment: i know this. I don't want a sorted array and doing the job. I need these with locations you know. You know like in this : input : abc def abe abc def deg entered unique ones : abc def abe deg if i sorted the array i will get unique ones like that : abc abe def deg This isn't what i want i need the locations aswell.

Comment: I don't think Mark did know, actually, since you didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: This is why i'm asking this :). I already know sorting and checking adjacent elements. But that's not solving my problem.

Comment: Sorting the array of indices as WhirlWind suggests should solve that.  It would leave the original order intact.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *data[20];
int i, j, n, unique[20];

n = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (!strcmp(data[i], data[unique[j]]))
           break;
    }

    if (j == n)
        unique[n++] = i;
}
```

The indexes of the first occurrence of each unique string should be in unique[0..n-1] if I did that right.

Comment: that seems really interesting, I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you starting second loop from 1?

You should start it from 
i+1. i.e.

```
for(j=i+1;j<20;j++)
```

Like if the list is

```
abc
def
abc
abc
lop
```

then

when i==4

tmp="lop"

but then the second loop starts which is from 1 to 19. This means it will get a value of 4 too at one stage, and then

data[4], which is "lop", will be same as tmp. So although "lop" is unique but it will be flagged as repeated.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: That is definitely not the main problem. Still O(n^2)

Comment: That really depends on your definition of "main problem".  This answer has identified a correctness problem, which is more severe than a performance problem.

Comment: @caf and @ Terry: Actually, in his question I did not find anything related to performance. 

His quote "But when i coded this the results were bad.(I handled all the memory stuff,little things etc.) The problem is in the second loop obviously :D. But i cannot think any solution. How do i find unique strings in an array."

So I only focused on that why his code is not working. Later, from other answers and comments I realised that discussion has taken a different shape.

Answer (score 2):

Think a bit more about your problem -- what you really want to do is look at the PREVIOUS strings to see if you've already seen it.  So, for each string `n`, compare it to strings `0` through `n-1`.

```
print element 0 (it is unique)
for i = 1 to n
  unique = 1
  for j = 0 to i-1 (compare this element to the ones preceding it)
    if element[i] == element[j]
       unique = 0
       break from loop
  if unique, print element i
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that your test is if (strcmp (this, that)) which will succeed if the two are different? !strcmp is probably what you want there.